# Visual Studio 2010 - Local File History

Tags: c#, version-control, team-foundation-server

I have been using netbeans for many years now and recently I have moved from PHP/Git/Netbeans to C#/TFS/VS10.

It has been very good so far, yet I miss this one little feature I enjoyed so much in Netbeans is... **local file history**.

Whenever I was working on something I could test different ideas and then simply reverting or even comparing changes at different time of the day or even different days.

I was wondering if there is any VS10 extension or some sort of plugin that would let me achieve similar functionality (internal version control sort of thing). *I would use TFS but we are only allow to check in our changes when they are actually read for production. Also I can't find revert changes button in TFS. I wouldn't want to create a branch either.*

I'm so desperate I was going to put hg or git over my TFS folder just so I can achieve this I'm just hoping there is some better solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [shelve function of TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404.aspx). It is a bit cumbersome but will work. I create different shelve sets with descriptive naming convention. While searching on google I came up with this [auto shelve extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/080540cb-e35f-4651-b71c-86c73e4a633d/). I haven't used it but will surely try on Monday to see if it is useful.

Comment: I'll install auto-shelve extension to see if it meets my criteria. Are shelves accessible to other developers? I thought that one reason for having shelves in TFS is to share code without "checkin in"

Comment: Yes shelves are accessible to other developers. One issue is that if you shelve code from a branch you or another developer cannot unshelve to a different branch. But this is possible if you install the TFS power tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Mercurial repositories locally on my machine for the same reason and it's been working rather well, so it may not be such a desperate solution?

I don't use a plugin integrated with VS as I prefer just using the command line, though I believe some are available for various source control options, e.g., for Git : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio

Comment: Ah I see. I use hg tortoise for my other (on the side) projects. I might try if that works a bit better. Not perfect though since I have to remember to commit all the time TFS and HG.... Lets hope someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 with TFS installed will give you the option in the context menu for each file to "Get Specific Version".  From there, you can get any copy of the file that has been checked in.

If you want to be able to work with multiple versions of the file without worrying about losing your changes, then I agree with @Pratik that using shelve sets is your best bet.

Comment: Seems very cumbersome for a simple feature which has been in net beans for quite a while now.